# MongoDB vs File Caching

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching

I am using a website with a MongoDB and I was wondering if this idea could be a good impact in the speed of serving data.

---

I have a database with MongoDB which serves to the users a list of customised notifications (they tend to be always the same unless there is a new one into the list).

**Current script**

- Users retrieve the customised data by using the web API and they check if there is new content every minute. (e.g `.find().sort('date').limit(20)`)
  (each user has different data stored)
- The calls are made with a simple `$.ajax` call and all the info is received in a JSON response with all data (last 20 entries in the database)
- An automated script running all time in node.js pushes these values into the database every minute approx.
- User only receives data, Server only pushes new data into the database

[image]

**Question**

- I know MongoDB uses its own caching system but, what about if the node.js script generates a JSON file ready for each specific user?

This way, the server would be serving the specific JSON file all time and not using the database for checking changes.

**Note that each user would have its individual JSON file**

[image]

> Would this solution be more efficient ? The script on the server side
>   would still keep a copy into the MongoDB (just in  case) but at the
>   same point it would update the JSON file for the users if necessary.
>   Users won't check for the database with this method.

Thanks

Comment: This would most likely help. Another way would be to use a memcache which would be even quicker (however it depends on the spec of your memcache and the number of users you have.)